# django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: python, django, docker

This occurs when running the code, docker-compose exec web python manage.py makemigrations users.

Below is my docker-compose.yml code.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:11
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testpassword
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Below is my Dockerfile code:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.8


# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code


# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system


# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

Upon runnning "docker compose up" in command, I receive the following message, ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: Duplicate mount point: /var/lib/postgresql/data
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: It may be because you have a trailing slash, try removing it `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Comment: I tried removing the trailing slash and it did not work.

Comment: Can you try running `docker-compose down -v --remove-orphans` to remove any already running containers and volumes?

Comment: I did and it returned, ERROR: No container found for web_1.

Comment: You need to start your services before you can `exec` a command - `docker-compose up -d`